# Azure DevOps project description page (a dynamic readMe file possible?)

Tags: github, azure-devops, readme

I have seen some informative Azure DevOps Project description pages (readMe file), where one can see at a first glance how the whole project is performing and would like to do something similar and want to know from where the information is coming and how to keep it up to date with the latest build/deploy status?

Something I have in mind is similar to this. Especially those green / red labeled indicators, which are also found sometimes in some GitHub repository readMe pages

[image]

example 2:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is to setup a pipeline dedicated to update your `README`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61221098/6309).

This is illustrated in the official documentation "[Add a status badge to your repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser#add-a-status-badge-to-your-repository)"

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/media/azure-pipelines-succeeded.png?view=azure-devops]

Comment: Sounds very promising. Thank you for the links. Will try it and see if I can get it to work.