# Programmatically replicating Devops UI organization-wide search feature to create Wiki article of READMEs?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I want to take the concept of creating dynamic README files whenever a new push is committed to a branch (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212433/is-it-possible-to-have-a-azure-pipeline-modify-a-readme-md-on-commit/61221098#61221098)) and take that one step further by creating a Wiki entry in a separate Project that will generate a list of all README files published.

Concept would be like this:

```
Organization A
-> Project A
--> Repo I
--> Repo II
--> Repo III
-> Project B
--> Repo I
--> Repo II
-> Project C - Development Group Central Hub
[this is where the Wiki is]
```

Theory of steps is:

1. Push code for README to generate with script
2. Run script every night that uses Azure CLI/Devops REST API/some other means to search across all projects, all repositories, using "master" branch to find a README for that repository
3. If the repository has a README, copy the URL of the README, name and description of the repository, and save it to Project C's Wiki as a new or updated page

I've been looking through documentation and found the "https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/[Organization]/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=7.1-preview.1" link to search within code, but it requires "Project" and "Repository" params.

The functional equivalency of this aggregator would be like going to the main page of Organization A and searching "all repositories" for the keyword "README.md" and then having the list of files that can be clicked on to take you to the file within the repo within the project.

Is there something already built that can do this, or do I have to list all projects and repos and then search for my keywords in each one in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in feature to do the steps. You need to achieve it with several steps:

1. Create the wiki with either DevOps CLI or DevOps Rest api.

   DevOps rest api for example: [Wikis - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and [Wikis - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).

   You need to prepare the content before you use the rest api.
2. Then you can use rest api to [list the wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) in the organization and project **in a loop**, get the wiki url in the response.
3. After you grant the wiki url, update `Project C's Wiki` content with above `Wiki - Update` rest
   api. The content can use [Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) like：

[image]

4. To run script every night, you can put the script in devops pipeline, and set with [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).